# How to view multiple stack traces while debugging a multi-threaded java application in Intellij?

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, remote-debugging

I am new to Intellij editor and was trying to debug my java application. While debugging multi-threaded application in eclipse, I could follow each thread by looking at its stack trace in debug mode. However in Intellij, even if two threads are executing a block of code, no two separate stack trace are observed in Debug window.
Are there any settings to enable this functionality?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can switch between the threads in the drop-down list above the stack trace.

[image]